# Using iterator to find an element in a doubly linked list in java

Tags: java, iterator, doubly-linked-list

Unfortunately, my code shows me only the result when the target is not in the list, and even for the one in the list it shows me that it is not found. I know I miss something small but got tired searching it. Please help me find the missing piece. Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean contains( T target ) {
    if(isEmpty())
        return false;
        
    ListIterator iter = new ListIterator();
    
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (iter.next().equals(target)) {
            System.out.println("target  found!");
            return true;
        }else {
                        
            System.out.println("target not found!");
            return false;
        }
                 
             
    }  
    
    modChange++; 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't ```return false;``` if ```!iter.next().equals(target)```. Otherwise, the remaining elements will not be checked.

Comment: equals() compares "Objects" not values! There is a T object there the same as another of it so it is true every test.     Where is the construction of the instance java.util.LinkedList E.  as much it may be saying null == null because the add() is using int not an object E